# how to add entry form in HTML 5 and JQuery web template?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, html, sql-server-2008

Nice to meet you, sorry i'm newbie here, this forum is my favourite reference and the first way I look for if I got any trouble, and I'm proud can join with all of you.

I want to develop web app with Visual Studio 2010 (VB.Net) and using SQL Server 2008 R2. And then I search all of free css templates, I have found one template which i take a lot of my attention. The template is created by Sara Soueidan ([demo here](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/windows8-animations/demo/index.html)), very amazing template I think.

I've download the css template, and follow his instructions step by step, but still i can't make new page, and I can't add control form, such as textbox, button, and so on.

I plan to use his template to make entry form and save the data using jQuery on SQL Server and I need help on that, any clue, so I can finish another page.

Thank you so much for your attention.

Animations [here](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/windows8-animations/).

Comment: "sorry i'm newbie here" - Please, no need to be sorry.

Comment: ah okay, my bad habit.. anyway thanks.